Table/figure notes environment: single-line centering, multi-line left-aligned
I am trying to define a custom tablenotes environment for adding notes below a table (or another float, like a figure). I want the notes to use the entire \textwidth as needed. The environment should:

Center the notes when they fit within a single line.
Left-align the notes without any indentation when they span multiple lines.

Below is my minimum working example. Despite my efforts to suppress indentation using \noindent and \parindent=0pt, a small indentation still appears when the notes run onto multiple lines.
How to define the environment so that the multi-line notes do not have any indentation while preserving centering for single-line notes?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Define the tablenotes environment
\newenvironment{tablenotes}{%
    \smallskip
    \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup
    \leavevmode % Enter horizontal mode explicitly
    \noindent
    \parindent=0pt % Ensure no indentation applies
}{%
    \egroup
    \leavevmode % Ensure consistent paragraph handling for output
    \ifdim\wd0<\linewidth
        \centerline{\unhbox0}%
    \else
        \noindent\unhbox0
    \fi
    \par
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        {\centering
            \begin{tabular}{cc}
                \hline
                Header 1 & Header 2 \\
                \hline
                Data 1   & Data 2   \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \par}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            A single line of notes. It is centered without any issue.
        \end{tablenotes}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            This is a longer piece of text that spans multiple lines. Each 
            line should be aligned to the left margin without any 
            indentation. \textbf{But as you can see, there is a small 
            indentation at the start of this text (before ``This is 
            \dots'').}
        \end{tablenotes}
        
    \end{table}
    
    This paragraph shows the normal text width for reference. \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}



You see the space which is after \parindent=0pt. You should take care of spaces in command and environment definition (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/316068 for example).

Just add %  after \begin{tablenotes},  i.e. it should be \begin{tablenotes}%

@jlab the space after \parindent=0pt gets consumed in processing.

@cfr If I replace \parindent=0pt % Ensure no indentation applies by \parindent=0pt% Ensure no indentation applies I get the desired output.

Caption's single line check uses a savebox (\hbox) and checks the width.  If longer than \hsize, it reformats it using \parbox{\hsize}{\unhbox...} or something like that.

@jlab so what does x\parindent=0pt y give you?

@tvk First of all, I think,  \begin{tablenotes}...\end{tablenotes} has no real connection to the table, for which it is used. You may use it anywhere in the document, without knowing, to which table it is connected.

@cfr I agree. But then why \parindent=0pt% removes the undesired space?

Let's examine your tablenotes environment:
\newenvironment{tablenotes}{%
    \smallskip
    \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup
    \leavevmode % Enter horizontal mode explicitly
    \noindent
    \parindent=0pt % Ensure no indentation applies
}{%
    \egroup
    \leavevmode % Ensure consistent paragraph handling for output
    \ifdim\wd0<\linewidth
        \centerline{\unhbox0}%
    \else
        \noindent\unhbox0
    \fi
    \par
}


After \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup you're already in (restricted) horizontal mode, where \leavevmode, \noindent and \parindent=0pt do nothing at all.

\leavevmode is wrong in the “end” part.

You should instead issue \par at the beginning.

You should issue \ignorespaces after \bgroup.


% Define the tablenotes environment
\newenvironment{tablenotes}{%
  \par
  \smallskip % \medskip or \vspace{\topsep} would be better
  \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\ignorespaces
}{%
  \egroup
  \ifdim\wd0<\linewidth
    \centerline{\unhbox0}%
  \else
    \noindent\unhbox0
  \fi
  \par
}

With this definition, you'd get

However, it's clumsy, particularly in that it requires braces around \centering.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Define the tablenotes environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{tablenotes}{+b}
 {
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \tvk_tablenotes:n {#1}
  \end{minipage}
 }{}

\seq_new:N \l__tvk_tablenotes_seq
\box_new:N \l__tvk_tablenote_note_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tvk_tablenotes:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tvk_tablenotes_seq { \note } {#1}
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__tvk_tablenotes_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__tvk_tablenotes_seq
   {
    \par\smallskip
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__tvk_tablenote_note_box {##1}
    \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \l__tvk_tablenote_note_box > \textwidth }
     {##1}
     { \hbox_to_wd:nn {\textwidth} {\hss##1\hss} }
    \par
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
Header 1 & Header 2 \\
\hline
Data 1   & Data 2   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\note A single line of notes. It is centered without any issue.
\note This is a longer piece of text that spans multiple lines. Each 
  line should be aligned to the left margin without any 
  indentation. \textbf{But as you can see, there is no small 
  indentation at the start of this text (before ``This is 
  \dots'').}
\end{tablenotes}
        
\end{table}
    
This paragraph shows the normal text width for reference. \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}

Notes are separated by the \note command (like \item in lists).

Addendum
If tablenotes is only supposed to contain one kind of notes, without paragraph breaks, you can simplify the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Define the tablenotes environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{tablenotes}{b}
 {
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \tvk_tablenotes:n {#1}
  \end{minipage}
 }{}

\box_new:N \l__tvk_tablenote_note_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tvk_tablenotes:n
 {
  \par\smallskip
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__tvk_tablenote_note_box {#1}
  \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \l__tvk_tablenote_note_box > \textwidth }
   {#1}
   { \hbox_to_wd:nn {\textwidth} {\hss#1\hss} }
  \par
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{This is the caption for the first table}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
Header 1 & Header 2 \\
\hline
Data 1   & Data 2   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
A single line of notes. It is centered without any issue.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{table}

Some text in the middle. \lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{This is the caption for the second table}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
Header 1 & Header 2 \\
\hline
Data 1   & Data 2   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
  This is a longer piece of text that spans multiple lines. Each 
  line should be aligned to the left margin without any 
  indentation. \textbf{But as you can see, there is no small 
  indentation at the start of this text (before ``This is 
  \dots'').}
\end{tablenotes}
        
\end{table}
    
\end{document}



This is amazing—thank you! Would it be possible to adjust the definition so that the notes don’t need to begin with \note inside the tablenotes environment? While my MWE demonstrates the alignment differences between single-line and multi-line notes, in practice, each table will always include just one note.

@tvk Added the code

I would use \ignorespaces
\newenvironment{tablenotes}{%
    \smallskip%
    \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup%
    \ignorespaces
}{%
    \egroup%
    \par%
    \ifdim\wd0<\linewidth%
        \centerline{\unhbox0}%
    \else%
        \noindent\unhbox0
    \fi
    \par
}

or directly the body of the environment that can be catched with +b using \NewDocumentEnvironment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{tablenotes}{ +b }
{%
  \smallskip
  \par
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \ifdim \wd0 < \linewidth%
    \centerline{\unhbox0}%
  \else%
    \noindent\unhbox0%
  \fi%
  \par
}
{}

EDIT After @egreg nice answer I removed the useless \leavevmode commands and add a \par in definitions.
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Define the tablenotes environment
\newenvironment{tablenotes}{%
  \smallskip%
  \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \egroup%
  \par%
  \ifdim\wd0<\linewidth%
    \centerline{\unhbox0}%
  \else%
    \noindent\unhbox0
  \fi
  \par
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{tablenotesvariant}{ +b }
{%
  \smallskip
  \par
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \ifdim \wd0 < \linewidth%
    \centerline{\unhbox0}%
  \else%
    \noindent\unhbox0%
  \fi%
  \par
}
{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  With \texttt{\textbackslash{}newenvironment}

  \begin{tablenotes}
    A single line of notes. It is centered without any issue.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \begin{tablenotes}
    This is a longer piece of text that spans multiple lines. Each
    line should be aligned to the left margin without any
    indentation.
  \end{tablenotes}

\end{table}

\begin{table}
  With \texttt{\textbackslash{}NewDocumentEnvironment}

  \begin{tablenotesvariant}
    A single line of notes. It is centered without any issue.
  \end{tablenotesvariant}
  \begin{tablenotesvariant}
    This is a longer piece of text that spans multiple lines. Each
    line should be aligned to the left margin without any
    indentation.
  \end{tablenotesvariant}

\end{table}

This paragraph shows the normal text width for reference. \lipsum[1]

\end{document}



I have defined another approach to the notes.
This is not an answer specific to the question, but please take a look. I think, with multiple centered notes of variable length, the whole table would not look good anymore.
For testing, uncomment the line:
%\centering %uncomment to test
My definitions are plainTeX,
I do not use LaTeX often, LaTeXers might give better definitions.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent=0pt
\newcount\notesnum
\notesnum=0
\def\note#1{\global\advance\notesnum by 1\textsuperscript{\the\notesnum}\immediate\write\notes{\noexpand \textsuperscript{\the\notesnum}#1 \vskip\baselineskip} }
\def\inputnotes{\global\notesnum=0
 \vskip\baselineskip
{\bf Tablenotes}\vskip\baselineskip
\immediate\closeout\notes 
\small \input \jobname.nt \vskip0.2\baselineskip{\bf End of table}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \newwrite\notes
\immediate\openout\notes=\jobname.nt 
        {\begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{cc}
                \hline
                Header  \note{A single line of notes. It is centered without any issue.}   & Header \note{Another note} \\
                \hline
                Data & Data \note{This is a longer piece of text that spans multiple lines. Each line should be aligned to the left margin without any indentation. But as you can see, there is a small indentation at the start of this text (before ``This is').} \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular} 
\end{center}}  
 %\centering %uncomment to test
 \inputnotes
    \end{table}
    This paragraph shows the normal text width for reference. \lipsum[1]
\end{document}

